# How to force reload data for an Android APP

Tags: android, caching, memory

I have an Android device. There is a navigation APP on this Android device that plays a sound every time i reach my destination.

I want to change this sound it makes, but the actual APP doesn't have a menu to do so.

What i did so far was:
- Scan my whole device with ES explorer for audio files. I've found  one .wav file and it is the one I'm after. I deleted the file and replaced it with another .wav file of my choosing.(same name, similar size, bitrate, etc).

Didn't work. Old file still plays from who-knows-where.

I went to menu and cleared cache for the app.

Didn't work.

I restart the phone, load new maps to phone and do whatever else i can think of. Nothing works.

I can't clear data for the app and force it to reload the sound because I have settings for the app inside and no backup possible.

I believe there old sounds is saved somewhere in a temp folder but i can't access it because no root and the app doesn't work on rooted phones. The old sounds it plays isn't even anywhere on the phone, i deleted it.

Can anyone think of another option to get my new file to play?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about programming, its about how to use an android device.

Answer (score 0):

During app development, a sound file such as the one to play when destination is reached might have been included in the res folder of the app.
Have a look into this: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/108691 
I'm not discouraging you to pursue this further, but be prepared to find that it might not be possible(just yet).

Comment: Hi. The file is there, clear as day in .wav format.  it's just that changing it or removing it does nothing which buffles me. After installation it puts it in its app folder and then reads it from somewhere else?